# Excel VBA Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, range, subscript

I modified a script to cut a big chunck of data into small pieces to keep subscript in the range.

I suppose to import data into spreadsheet, but it says

```
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range
```

Code

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click()
    Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
    Dim Last As Integer: Last = W.Range("b2000").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Last1 As Integer
    Dim Symbols As String
    Dim i, n, x, y As Integer

    Last1 = Last - CInt(Last / 10) * 9

    x = 5
    For n = Last1 To Last Step CInt(Last / 10)
        For i = x To n
            Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("b" & i).Value & "+"
        Next i
        x = i
        'Stop
        Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

        Debug.Print Symbols
        'Stop

        Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=snxl1c7g0h0" & Cells(2, 11) & "j0k0va2j1e7rs7dy"
        Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
        Http.Open "GET", URL, False
        Http.Send

        Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
        Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)

        Dim sLine As String
        y = 5
        For i = y To n
            sLine = Lines(i)
            Debug.Print sLine
            'Stop

            If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
                Values = Split(sLine, ",")
                W.Cells(i, 3).Value = Split(Split(sLine, Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))(1), Chr(34))(0)
                W.Cells(i, 4).Value = Split(Split(sLine, Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34))(2), Chr(34))(0)
                W.Cells(i, 5).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 14)
                W.Cells(i, 6).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 13)
                W.Cells(i, 7).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 12)
                W.Cells(i, 8).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 11)
                W.Cells(i, 9).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 10)
                W.Cells(i, 10).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 9)
                W.Cells(i, 11).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 8)
                W.Cells(i, 12).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 7)
                W.Cells(i, 13).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 6)
                W.Cells(i, 14).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 5)
                W.Cells(i, 15).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 4)
                W.Cells(i, 16).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 3)
                W.Cells(i, 17).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 2)
                W.Cells(i, 18).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 1)
                W.Cells(i, 19).Value = Values(UBound(Values))
            End If
        Next i
        Symbols = ""
    Next n
    W.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: L34--->    sLine = Lines(i)

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of your code so you can make sure you don't mess any of your variables up.

Subscript out of range means that the program declares (DIM) an array to be of a certain length, but tries to reference an element with a subscript greater than the actual length. Often, but not always, this happens because a loop goes one index too far. Another common cause is using an index that has never been assigned a valid value.

Comment: Okay! That's what I am trying to get over. The website can query max of 200 entities at one time, and the data list needed to be processed is greater than 200, so I break the original list into several small pieces to try to overcome out of range issue.

Comment: Well, I still haven't figured out where the bug is. Thank you for your respond. I will mark it, if I fix the problem by your advice. :-)